# Polymaps / Tilestache tiling grid mismatch

Tags: vector, geojson, polymaps, tilestache

I have set up a basic PostGIS / Tilestache / gunicorn / nginx / Polymaps test environment, rendering my dataset from PostGIS to GeoJSON and shipping it out to be rendered in Polymaps.

That works nicely, but for one small detail: Polymaps seems not to be requesting all tiles.

If my dataset encompasses a world map, at zoom level 0, it requests 0/0/0.geojson, but not 0/1/0.geojson (the Eastern hemisphere). If I zoom further into the visible dataset, the right halves of it seem to disappear.

With a more local dataset (Norway, display centered around lat/lon 60/10) nothing at all is displayed. One correct tile to load and display would for example be 2/4/0.geojson, which spans the whole dataset. Polymaps never loads any tile with an index above 3.

If I load the tile directly, ignoring the tiling scheme, it is loaded and displayed correctly.

Any clues to what I am missing? 
Polymaps code below:

```
var po = org.polymaps;

var map = po.map()
.container(document.getElementById("map").appendChild(po.svg("svg")))
.center({lat: 60, lon: 10})
.zoomRange([0, 20])
.zoom(10)
.add(po.interact())
.add(po.hash());
```

loading the tiled layer:

```
map.add(po.geoJson() 
.url("/boundary/{Z}/{X}/{Y}.geojson")
.id("boundary")
.on("load", loadFeature))
```

loading the one tile directly (works):

```
map.add(po.geoJson()
.url("/test.geojson")
.id("boundary2")
.on("load", loadFeature))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, got it myself - the tiling scheme mismatch was between WSG84 in tilestache and spherical mercator in Polymaps.